# Ansible. Iterate over uniq element

Tags: ansible

Say I have this object:

```
myobj:
  - name: alice
    location: denver
  - name: mary
    location: denver
  - name: roy
    location: paris
```

What would be an easy way to uniquely loop over the location in this object?

I can create a new object by first looping over myobj en set new facts but I think there should be a nicer way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can extract locations and loop over it. for example:

```yaml
  - debug:
      msg: "location {{ item }}"
    loop: "{{ locations }}"
    vars:
      myobj:
        - name: alice
          location: denver
        - name: mary
          location: denver
        - name: roy
          location: paris
      locations: "{{ myobj | map(attribute='location') | unique }}"
```

output:

```
TASK [debug] ****************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=denver) => {
    "msg": "location denver"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=paris) => {
    "msg": "location paris"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ***How to loop over the key `location` in this dict?***

A minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    myobj:
      - name: alice
        location: denver
      - name: mary
        location: denver
      - name: roy
        location: paris

  tasks:

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ item }}"
    loop: "{{ myobj | selectattr('location', 'defined') | map(attribute='location') }}"
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] **********************
ok: [localhost] => (item=denver) =>
  msg: denver
ok: [localhost] => (item=denver) =>
  msg: denver
ok: [localhost] => (item=paris) =>
  msg: paris
```

... or just in short `{{ myobj | map(attribute='location') }}`.

It is also possible to apply additional filer like [`unique` filter – set of unique items of a list](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/unique_filter.html).

**Credits To**

- [How to work with a list of dictionaries in Ansible](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/ansible-jinja-lists-dictionaries)

Comment: Do you think you can make the location unique? i.e. denver only occurs once?

Comment: That's already in the answers here. Just apply an additional filter like in `{{ myobj | selectattr('location', 'defined') | map(attribute='location') | unique }}`.